# Differences between Javascript regexp literal and constructor

Tags: javascript, regex

We recently had a bug, after a fellow developer changed a RegExp literal into a constructor call, and I was wondering why there is any difference at all.
The exact code was

```
var parts = new RegExp("/rt:([^@]+)@(\d+)/").exec(tag);
```

vs the original of

```
var parts = /rt:([^@]+)@(\d+)/.exec(tag);
```

When `tag` is, for example `rt:60C1C036-42FA-4073-B10B-1969BD2358FB@00000000077`, the first (buggy) call returns `null`, while the second one returns`["rt:60C1C036-42FA-4073-B10B-1969BD2358FB@00000000077", "60C1C036-42FA-4073-B10B-1969BD2358FB", "00000000077"]`

Needless to say, I reverted the change, but I'd like to know why is there such a difference in the first place.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are two problems:

The `/` are **not** part of the expression. They are *delimiters*, marking a regex literal. They have to be removed if you use `RegExp`, otherwise they match a slash literally.

Secondly, the backslash is the escape character in string literals. To create a literal `\` for the expression, you have to escape it in the string.

Thus, the equivalent would be:

```
new RegExp("rt:([^@]+)@(\\d+)")
```

---

Especially  the escaping makes expression a bit more difficult to write if you want to use `RegExp`. It is actually only needed if you want to create expression dynamically, that is, if you want to include text stored in a variable for example. If you have a fixed expression, a literal `/.../` is easier to write and more concise.

Comment: Good answer, think I'll delete mine! What if you need to reuse a particular RegExp - is that not a good time to use a constructor? Or would you just say `var resuasableRegex = /..pattern../;` ?

Comment: @ElRonnoco: Exactly, you can assign a regex literal to a variable as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Next time I'll look into the strings better, to make sure there are no escape characters needed.
Anyway, literal is much easier for sure.

Comment: For small regex, literals are definitely the way to go. If you have a dynamic expression or a very long regex to maintain, RegExp is a nice option. Escaping isn't too bad: just "double the [literal] backslashes and escape the quotes" Javascript - The Good Parts, p. 71. Here's code that will get just the quotes: `function escape(text) { return text.replace(/['"]/g, "\\$&"); };`

Answer (score 4):

`\d` needs to be escaped when passesd to `new RegExp` constructor. So, it needs to be

```
var parts = new RegExp("rt:([^@]+)@(\\d+)").exec(tag);
```