# How do I check if a string is of the form 10*10*10 using Javascript/JQuery and then do math

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to dynamically calculate volume based on the input of some carton dimensions.

e.g a For a carton with dimensions 10cm x 10cm x 10cm the user inputs 10*10*10 into a text input.

My javascript will then check to see if the input matches this pattern and do the math and populate another input with the result. 10 x 10 x 10 = 1000.

I think I need to use Regular Expressions which I don't have much experience with. The code below stops working at the match stage.(Invalid regular expression: /d+*d+*d+/: Nothing to repeat) Although I'm pretty sure I don't know what I'm doing after that.

Can anyone help?

```
carton_dimensions=$(this).val();

var pattern = "(\d+)\*(\d+)\*(\d+)";    
var result = carton_dimensions.match(pattern); 


if(result){

    volume=result[0]*result[1]*result[2];

}
```

Comment: Use a regex literal notation: `var pattern = /(\d+)\*(\d+)\*(\d+)/;`. See [*Differences between Javascript regexp literal and constructor*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964916/differences-between-javascript-regexp-literal-and-constructor).

Comment: `Nothing to repeat` is thrown because JS RegExp does not allow quantifying the quantifiers (like in `+*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `pattern` is worngly declared, it should be without `"` but `/`:

```
var pattern = /(\d+)\*(\d+)\*(\d+)/;
```

Also, the results you are looking for are in the indexes 1,2 and 3:

```
volume = result[1] * result[2] * result[3];
```

So, your final code must something like this:

```
carton_dimensions = $("input").val();

var pattern = /(\d+)\*(\d+)\*(\d+)/;    
var result = carton_dimensions.match(pattern); 

if(result){
    volume = result[1] * result[2] * result[3];
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbf6pjtu/1/) with a working example.

Answer (score 2):

```
"(\d+)\*(\d+)\*(\d+)"
^                   ^
```

is a string literal. What you need is a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_regular_expression):

```
/(\d+)\*(\d+)\*(\d+)/
^                   ^
```

Alternatively you can use the `RegExp` constructor, but then you have to deal with escaping special characters within the string literal so the *value* is equivalent to the regular expression that you intend to use:

```
new RegExp("(\\d+)\\*(\\d+)\\*(\\d+)")
```

Comment: There is no point in using a constructor notation since the pattern is not dynamic. If the pattern is user-defined, then it is a must.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, absolutely. I mentioned it just to show the alternative, not as a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

For the calculation, you can use javascript's eval like this:

`var answer = eval(result[0] + '*' + result[1] + '*' + result[2]);`

And since you are validating the input, you should be safe.