# Occurrences counter in a string by variable

Tags: javascript

I'd like to count the number of occurrences in a string by variable, bu i can't find a working method.
I first found this method in another thread that found the number of occurencies in a string by another string :

```js
var temp = "This is a string.";
var count = (temp.match(/is/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

And tried to modify it by replacing the "is" by a variable :

```js
var temp = "This is a string.";
var t = 'is'
var count = (temp.match('/'+t+'/g') || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

And it founds 0 occurrence...

Answer (score 2):

In the example you've found they use RegExp literal. However, literals cannot contain variable parts, so you just need to create a RegExp object explicitly instead:

```js
var temp = "This is a string.";
var t = 'is'
var count = (temp.match(new RegExp(t, 'g')) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

see [JavaScript: RegExp constructor vs RegEx literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911960/javascript-regexp-constructor-vs-regex-literal) for more info