# Allow integer inside parentheses

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a regular expression so that only such numbers:
`2977777`, `(032)2977777`, `297-77-77`, `297 77 77` can be entered.

On the site regexr.com, this `(\((032)\))?(297)([\- ]?7{2}){2}` expression works 
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y34T.png),the program doesn't work only for this number `(032)2977777`
[Result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjjVr.png)

```js
form.addEventListener(
  "submit",
  function(event) {              //i think problem in \( and \) 
    var IndexTemplate = new RegExp("(\((032)\))?(297)([- ]?7{2}){2}");
    if (numberInput.value.length === 0) {
      numberLvivSpan.innerHTML = "Please enter the phone!";
      numberLvivSpan.className = "error active";
      event.preventDefault();
    } else if (!numberInput.value.replace(IndexTemplate, "").length) {
      numberLvivSpan.innerHTML = "Invalid phone!";
      numberLvivSpan.className = "error good";
      setTimeout(() => {
        numberLvivSpan.innerHTML = "";
        numberLvivSpan.className = "error";
      }, 1000);

      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      numberLvivSpan.innerHTML = "Phone is valid!";
      numberLvivSpan.className = "error active";
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: Your regex works for me

Comment: @ControlAltDel check my new result in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the **new** operator for creating the **RegExp**, you need to scape the backslash chatacters in the String.

I recommmend you to use the literal RegExp if the expression is static.

[Differences between Javascript regexp literal and constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964916/differences-between-javascript-regexp-literal-and-constructor)

So the fixed code should be like this:

```js
form.addEventListener(
  "submit",
  function(event) {              //i think problem in \( and \) 
    var IndexTemplate = /(\((032)\))?(297)([- ]?7{2}){2}/;
    if (numberInput.value.length === 0) {
      numberLvivSpan.innerHTML = "Please enter the phone!";
      numberLvivSpan.className = "error active";
      event.preventDefault();
    } else if (!numberInput.value.replace(IndexTemplate, "").length) {
      numberLvivSpan.innerHTML = "Invalid phone!";
      numberLvivSpan.className = "error good";
      setTimeout(() => {
        numberLvivSpan.innerHTML = "";
        numberLvivSpan.className = "error";
      }, 1000);

      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      numberLvivSpan.innerHTML = "Phone is valid!";
      numberLvivSpan.className = "error active";
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  false
);
```

### Update: when use literal and when use RegExp constructor.

For static RegExp, which won't change during you web application execution, you can use both but it is preferred to use the literal method for avoiding string scaped characters common mistakes.

For dynamic RegExp, which depends on an input, you can only use constructor method for creating RegExp. An example of this could be an implementation of a **replaceAll** method, which accepts the input you want to replace in the whole string.

Here you have the Mozilla documentation about RegExp in JavaScript with some examples of literal and constructor method.

[MDN RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: When we need use a constructor?